# Expand Radtextbox when button clicked

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I have created a text box which shows just one row.

Trying to trigger the event, when button clicked expand it it to 5 rows.

```
        function noteboxFocus() {
            alert("HI");
            var v = document.getElementById('<%=ComAlertMHIP.ClientID%>').value;
            $(v).attr('rows', 5);
        }
```

Can some one please help me.

This is my textbox:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="ComAlertMHIP" Runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" rows="1" ShowButton="true" ClientEvents-OnButtonClick="noteboxFocus"> </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Comment: <telerik:RadTextBox ID="ComAlertMHIP" Runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" rows="1"   ShowButton="true" ClientEvents-OnButtonClick="noteboxFocus">
</telerik:RadTextBox>     this is my textbox

Comment: Does it work if you declare a button external to the textbox and fire the function on the button's onClientClick event? (Does what you have above cause the alert box to show up?)

Comment: The alert box shows up when I click the button, but not able to expand the textbox.

Comment: So one of the two lines following the alert is failing. Which one? Throw a "debugger;" in and look at v after the first line. Is it finding it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function noteboxFocus() {
        alert("HI");
        var v = document.getElementById('<%=ComAlertMHIP.ClientID%>');
       v.rows = 10
    }
```

Its element that I wanted was triggering value and that was the issue, this code had fixed and works fine.